# Preorder magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, preorder

Anybody know a way to create a preorder on Magento 1.9.
I need to create an order and send a link to my customer to pay it later.
But the most important thing is that as a user I should be able to go to checkout page.

Actually, my problem is that the stock in some products is reduced to zero, in that situation users can't go to the checkout and can't complete the order.

Comment: you may consider to move your question to magento.stackexchange.com, since your question is not related to programming whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

simply enable backorders

```
System > Config > Inventory
```

This setting will only affect new products. Already existing products need to be edited to accept backorders

Comment: Thanks, I know that. The problem is that I have old products that Will never come back to the store. I can offer those products as blackorders.

Comment: So why don't you leave those products in regular stock an use backorders for available products?

Comment: Coul be. I need to ask my boss about that. Will be a great solution.